# subscript out of bound error when calibrating a cox model

Tags: r, error-handling, survival-analysis, cox-regression, calibration

I am using the `rms` package for a cox model:

```
rmsfit2 <- cph(Surv(time,stop, Lstate) ~ gender+momedu+sibs+L1.Spostureaway_re+
                 L1.Sgazeaw_re +  L1.Sgazepic_re+ frailty(id), x=TRUE, y=TRUE, surv = TRUE, data=data2step)
```

I had no problem when using the `validate()` function `validate(rmsfit2, method = "boot", B = 100)`
which returned:

```
      index.orig training   test optimism index.corrected   n
Dxy       0.2711   0.2698 0.2671   0.0027          0.2684 100
R2        0.0582   0.0577 0.0562   0.0015          0.0568 100
Slope     1.0000   1.0000 0.9785   0.0215          0.9785 100
D         0.0122   0.0120 0.0117   0.0003          0.0119 100
U        -0.0001  -0.0001 0.0001  -0.0001          0.0001 100
Q         0.0122   0.0121 0.0116   0.0004          0.0118 100
g         0.3162   0.3154 0.3066   0.0088          0.3075 100
```

However, I couldn't get the `calibrate()` function `calibrate(rmsfit2, B = 20)` to work. It returned an error message `Error in reliability[, "index.corrected"] : subscript out of bounds`.

I don't know what is the best way to reproduce this error with the sample data shipped with `survival` or `rms` packages but does anyone have any insight on this problem and how to make it work? Thank you!